# The type of expression must be array type error JAVA

Tags: java

```
package p1;
public class Matrix{


    public Matrix(int b,Vector...vectors) {

    double myArray[][] = new double[vectors.length][];
    int row = vectors.length;

    int column = vectors.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        myArray[i] = new double[column];
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {

            if(b==0)
            {

                myArray[i][j] = vectors[i][j]; // ERROR HERE
            }
            else
            {
                myArray[j][i] = vectors[i][j]; // ERROR HERE
        }
    }
}
}

}
```

Error: The type of expression must be array type error but it resolved to vector

I cannot integrate two vectors into one 2d array

The definition of the `Vector` class is below:

```
public class Vector { 

    public double[] getYourArray() { 
        return yourArray; 
    } 

    public void setYourArray(double[] yourArray) { 
        this.yourArray = yourArray; 
    }  

    public double yourArray[]; 

    public Vector(double...yourArray) { 
        this.yourArray = yourArray;                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What `Vector` is that?

Comment: Vector class: holds a vetor of real numbers as a one dimensional array.
Constructors:
(1) Takes an array of doubles and convert to aVector
(2) Takes a comma seprated doubles as a list and convert them into a Vector.

Comment: public class Vector {
 
   public double[] getYourArray() {
  return yourArray;
 }






 public void setYourArray(double[] yourArray) {
  this.yourArray = yourArray;
 }






  public double yourArray[];
    
 




 public Vector(double...yourArray) {
      this.yourArray = yourArray;
      
      
 }


 
}

Comment: `vectors[i]` is a `Vector`, not an array so you cannot use `[x]` on it. Maybe you need  `vectors[i].getYourArray()[j]`

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: and what if; (3) Taking an integer and producing an Identity matrix of dimension determined by that integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the definition of the `Vector` class you have provided the following should fix your code:

```
package p1;
public class Matrix {

    public Matrix(int b,Vector...vectors) {

        double myArray[][] = new double[vectors.length][];
        int row = vectors.length;

        int column = vectors.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            myArray[i] = new double[column];
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                if(b==0) {
                    myArray[i][j] = vectors[i].getYourArray()[j]; // change made here
                } else {
                    myArray[j][i] = vectors[i].getYourArray()[j]; // change made here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i get row and column number to multiplyconstant method

Comment: It looks like you are representing a Matrix with a 2d array of doubles, so you can store the array as part of the Matrix object. For a `multiplyConstant(double constant)` method, you can then simply loop through every entry of the array with nested loops (similar to the way you did it in the constructor above) and multiply each entry by that constant.

Comment: Though if you have a specific problem with that you should probably post it as a separate question, since it is not related to the original problem anymore. If my answer solved your original problem, then please remember to accept the answer.